# Render arrays of a dictionary in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to render Arrays that are grouped via dictionaries. But I can't get it to work.

My code looks like this:

```
var dict: { [key: string] : Array<SomeObject>; };

public render(): React.ReactElement<IProps> {
  return (
    <Container>
      {
        this.dict.map((key, idx) =>
          <Row className={styles.dateColumn}>
            <Col sm={12} className={ styles.column }>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        )
      }
    </Container>
  )
}
```

But I get the following error message:

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'SomeObject[]' has no compatible call signatures.ts(2349)
```

I want to iterate through keys for the headline and iterate through its array values to render it beneath the right headline.

Like this:

```
- Key 1 
 - Value 1.1 
 - Value 1.2
 - Value 1.3
- Key 2
 - Value 2.1 
 - Value 2.2
 - Value 2.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining an object with **keys** of type `string`, and **value** of type `SomeObject[]`.

So, when you write `this.dict.map`, Typescript compiler act as if you are accessing object `this.dict` with the key `map` (Unlike `Array`, `Object` does not have `map` function).

`this.dict.map` return a value of `SomeObject[]`, which is an Array and not a function =  it is not `call-able`.

You might find using a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) more suitable for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Wow. Yea, totally right. Thank you so much. Sometimes JavaScript/TypeScript is a little bit tricky for C#-Developers. :D